# how to bind data to the formcontrolname in angular?

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

This is the sample form item inside my form for user to input while create new data :

```
<nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-label>{{ 'label.bank.number' | translate }}</nz-form-label>
    <nz-form-control [nzErrorTip]="'error.bank.number' | translate">
      <input nz-input formControlName="bankAccNo"/>
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
```

This is the sample hard code data :

```
this.bank.push(
  {
  id: '0',
  code: 'P0001',
  bankName: 'MayBank',
  bankNumber: '1231231233',
  currency: 'RM',
  status: 'Active'
},
{
  id: '1',
  code: 'P0002',
  bankName: 'Public Bank',
  bankNumber: '1231123145',
  currency: 'RM',
  status: 'Inactive'
});
```

What I try to achieve is when user press edit button, the input box with formControlName="bankAccNo" will retrieve the bankNumber data. Please help if you have any idea on how to do this, tried few solution but none of it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found to this question : https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName